# EXCEL VBA: Looking for code to rename a specified sheet with specified name, both based on cell values

Tags: excel, vba

So, say for instance I have 2 sheets in my workbook... `Page1` and `OldName`.
On sheet `Page1` in cell `A1` there is the value **OldName** (where "OldName" happens to be sheet name of the sheet I would like to rename).

Also on `Page1` in cell `A2`, there is the value **NewName** (where "NewName" is the name I would like to change the sheet specified in cell `A1` to).

I am Trying to come up with code that uses the the cell `A1` to identify which sheet I would like to rename and then use the cell `A2` as the source for the rename value.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something along these lines:

```
Sub Test()

Dim sht As Worksheet

With ThisWorkbook
    For Each sht In .Worksheets
        If sht.Name = .Worksheets("Page1").Cells(1, 1).Value Then
            sht.Name = .Worksheets("Page1").Cells(2, 1).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This did the trick perfectly, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

try this simple loop

```
Sub ChangeNameLoop()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim OldName As String, NewName As string

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
OldName = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")   '   location of names
NewName = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = OldName Then
        ws.Name = NewName
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to loop. This will do what you want. This code will replace the sheet name if found else will do nothing.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    On Error Resume Next
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets(.Sheets("Page1").Cells(1, 1).Value2).Name = _
        .Sheets("Page1").Cells(2, 1).Value2
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Or something like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = .Sheets(.Sheets("Page1").Cells(1, 1).Value2)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then ws.Name = _
        .Sheets("Page1").Cells(2, 1).Value2
    End With
End Sub
```